# calling a rest service on submission of form

Tags: forms, rest, spring-mvc

I have a form which has some values. When i submit the form i want the current logged in user's userid to be passed in the path to call a rest service handler in my controller. I don't know what to write in the form action to make it happen.

## my controller handler

```
@RequestMapping(value="/redemptionRedirect1/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Transaction submitRedemption(@PathVariable("userId") long userId ,@ModelAttribute("redemption") Transaction transaction)
    {
        boolean flag;
        Authentication auth =SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String name = auth.getName();
    User user=userService.getUser(name);
    transaction.setUser(user);
    flag = transactionService.addRedemptionTransactions(transaction);
    return transaction;
}
```

>

## my jsp

```
<body>
<form id="account" action="redemptionRedirect1/${user.userId}" method="get">
<table>
<tr><td>Amount: </td><td><input type="text" maxlength="5" value='<c:out      value="${amount}"/>' readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>
Bank Accounts: </td><td><select id="bankaccounts">
 <c:forEach items="${baccounts}" var="account">
<option value='<c:out value="${account.accountNumber}"/>'>
<c:out value="${account.name}"/>
 </option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
 </td></tr>
  <tr><td>Demat Account: </td><td><input type="text" placeholder='<c:out    value="${daccount.dematName}"/>' value='<c:out value="${daccount.dematAccountNumber}"/>'    readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
 <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Confirm"/></td></tr>
 </table>
 <div style="visibility: hidden;"><input id="user" type="text" value='<c:out    value="${user.userId}"/>'/></div>
 <div id="personFormResponse"></div>
 </form>

 </body>
```

Comment: right now it gives me error that requested resource not found.

Comment: In you browser, when you view source, does the forms action look correct?

Comment: yes the form action says Authorization/redemptionRedirect1/1 ... 1 is the userId here...which i guess should be correct..

Comment: If you call the url manually, does it work?

Comment: its still not working when i call directly from url..

Comment: That's good then - not your forms fault.  What is the exact error? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: its not showing any error in the console. But the usual resource not found error page is popping up.

Comment: Sorry what console are you talking about?  Is this webapp properly deployed?

Comment: no i was talking about the eclipse console. its not showing any error there. just this page of resource not found. i made this on my machine just for practice. so i m testing on my machine only.

Comment: Well basically the url that you are using does not match, how it is deployed.  I take it you have tried `http://localhost:8080/Authorization/redemptionRedirect1/1` from your browser.  Is Authorization correct?  Are any other pages working?

Comment: yes. there is a series of pages working correctly before this. but they had normal handlers not the handlers with responsebody. Basically what i m doing is entering some transaction details to be reflected into my DB. but what is before this every page is working but not this one.

Comment: i corrected my error. Thank you. i just put redemptionRedirect1/${user.userId} into my action instead of redemptionRedirect1/${user.userId}.htm. working now.

Comment: good to hear.  Sorry, with the amount of information you post here, it  would be impossible to debug that.